# How can I display (onload) an on/off button in html depending on a value in a mysql database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I want to display onload a (sort-of) toggle button depending on a value inside a table in a mysql database (the table has only one row) and also when I click it,I want to change a value in the same table from 0 to 1 or opposite. I've seen a lot of answers on related questions but non of them seem to be working for me. Some help will be much needed. Thanks a lot!

Here is my php code:

```
 <?php
 include 'db_ecoheating.php';
 mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass)  
or die ("Unable to connect to database");  

mysql_select_db($dbname)  
or die ("Unable to select database");  

$sql = "SELECT coil1 from coils ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $coil1 = $row['coil1'];

}
$arr = array(
  'value1'=> $coil1,
);
echo json_encode($arr);
  ?>
```

Also my function in js (inlcuding jquery):

```
function buttonFunctions(){
    var x1=document.getElementById("coil1");
    var value = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "coils.php",
        data: query,
        dataType: "json"
         success: function(data){
            console.log(data.value1);

        }
       });
    if(value=='0') coil1.src = "Button2.png";
            else if(value=='1') coil1.src = "Button1.png";
    //coil1.src="Button1.png";

   }
```

Also my image(working as a button):

```
<input type="image" onclick="saveData()" id="coil1"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the idea of using JS is OK, you could do that with plain PHP and HTML/CSS.
I also suggest you start using mysqli/PDO.

```
/*CSS */
.button0 {background-image: url("Button1.png");}
.button1 {background-image: url("Button2.png");}
```

Then, to show your button, use the following PHP code

```
 <?php
 include 'db_ecoheating.php';
 mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die ("Unable to connect to database");  

 mysql_select_db($dbname)  or die ("Unable to select database");  

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM coils";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $value = $row['coil1']; ?>

 <input class="button<?php echo $value; ?>" type="image" onclick="saveData()" id="coil1"/>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Apparently, it has a problem recognizing "button<?php echo $coil1; ?>". It takes it as a string.

Comment: Corrected the query and also changed the CSS classes to match the 0 and 1 values in your table. I assumed you coils table has a single row in the column coil1. If you have more rows, you need to find a way to filter your query. BTW ... you don't need that JQuery/AJAX  code you posted, i think.Well, depends very much on what the rest of your code looks like.

Comment: I still have that problem, I tried displaying a html code using php (with echo) , but doesn't work. Thank you anyway for your answers!